# SOAP: interface ... not visible from classloader

Tags: soap, java-8, weblogic14c

i am migrating my software from a weblogic 12 environment with java7 to a weblogic14 environment with java8. In my software there is a client for SOAP services which doesn't work in the new weblogic environment. I initially got the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to create FSBPxxxPayOTPPortType
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.internal.services.OTPAuthorizationServiceImpl$InitializingOTPHolder.loadPort(OTPAuthorizationServiceImpl.java:366) ~[na:na]
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.internal.services.OTPAuthorizationServiceImpl$InitializingOTPHolder.loadPort(OTPAuthorizationServiceImpl.java:344) ~[na:na]
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.internal.services.holders.InitializingWSHolder.getPort(InitializingWSHolder.java:31) ~[na:na]
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.internal.services.holders.SoapServiceEnpoint.getEndpoint(SoapServiceEnpoint.java:33) ~[na:na]
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.internal.services.OTPAuthorizationServiceImpl.verifyCard_aroundBody0(OTPAuthorizationServiceImpl.java:98) ~[na:na]
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.internal.services.OTPAuthorizationServiceImpl$AjcClosure1.run(OTPAuthorizationServiceImpl.java:1) ~[na:na]
    at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149) ~[aspectjrt-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.jcabi.aspects.aj.MethodLogger.wrap(MethodLogger.java:212) ~[jcabi-aspects-0.22.2.jar:na]
    at com.jcabi.aspects.aj.MethodLogger.ajc$inlineAccessMethod$com_jcabi_aspects_aj_MethodLogger$com_jcabi_aspects_aj_MethodLogger$wrap(MethodLogger.java:1) ~[jcabi-aspects-0.22.2.jar:na]
    at com.jcabi.aspects.aj.MethodLogger.wrapMethod(MethodLogger.java:169) ~[jcabi-aspects-0.22.2.jar:na]
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.internal.services.OTPAuthorizationServiceImpl.__M_verifyCard(OTPAuthorizationServiceImpl.java:90) ~[na:na]
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.internal.services.OTPAuthorizationServiceImpl.verifyCard(OTPAuthorizationServiceImpl.java) ~[na:na]
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.rest.resources.impl.UserPaymentToolsManager.getOTPEnabled(UserPaymentToolsManager.java:451) [rest-osgi-bundle-2.18.59.jar:na]
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.rest.resources.impl.UserPaymentToolsManager.getUserPaymentToolsInternal(UserPaymentToolsManager.java:211) [rest-osgi-bundle-2.18.59.jar:na]
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.rest.resources.impl.UserPaymentToolsManager.getUserPaymentTools(UserPaymentToolsManager.java:47) [rest-osgi-bundle-2.18.59.jar:na]
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.rest.resources.PaymentResource.getCartPaymentSummary(PaymentResource.java:431) [rest-osgi-bundle-2.18.59.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81) [jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144) [jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161) [jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205) [jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99) [jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389) [jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347) [jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102) [jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:309) [jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) [jersey-common-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) [jersey-common-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) [jersey-common-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) [jersey-common-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) [jersey-common-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317) [jersey-common-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:292) [jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1139) [jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:460) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:334) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:339) [org.apache.felix.http.bridge-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:300) [org.apache.felix.http.bridge-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:93) [org.apache.felix.http.bridge-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:50) [org.apache.felix.http.bridge-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31) [org.apache.felix.http.bridge-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:76) [org.apache.felix.http.bridge-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:49) [org.apache.felix.http.bridge-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67) [org.apache.felix.http.bridge-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750) [jakarta.servlet.jakarta.servlet-api.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.apache.felix.http.proxy.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60) [org.apache.felix.http.proxy-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750) [jakarta.servlet.jakarta.servlet-api.jar:4.0.2]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:295) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:353) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:250) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3865) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3832) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:344) [com.oracle.weblogic.security.subject.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197) [com.oracle.weblogic.security.subject.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.processSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2505) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2354) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2329) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2307) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1780) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1734) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352) [com.bea.core.utils.full.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337) [com.bea.core.utils.full.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57) [com.oracle.weblogic.work.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:651) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:14.1.1.0]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: MASM0015: Class [ com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.jaxws.HandlerTubeFactory ] does not implement [ com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.dev.TubeFactory ] interface
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.TubeCreator.<init>(TubeCreator.java:63) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblyController.initializeTubeCreators(TubelineAssemblyController.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblyController.getTubeCreators(TubelineAssemblyController.java:79) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.MetroTubelineAssembler.createClient(MetroTubelineAssembler.java:103) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.createPipeline(Stub.java:328) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:295) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:228) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:243) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.<init>(SEIStub.java:84) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getStubHandler(WSServiceDelegate.java:814) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:803) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:436) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:404) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:386) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:139) ~[na:2.3.2]
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.otp.FSBPxxxPayOTP.getSOAP11Port(FSBPxxxPayOTP.java:68) ~[na:na]
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.internal.services.OTPAuthorizationServiceImpl$InitializingOTPHolder.loadPort(OTPAuthorizationServiceImpl.java:359) ~[na:na]
    ... 76 common frames omitted
```

Please note that this is an osgi project. In another module (not osgi) I solved the problem by deleting the prefer resource from the weblogic.xml file

META-INF/services/javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider

and i did the same thing in this module too but now i get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to create FSBPxxxPayOTPPortType
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.itg.internal.services.OTPAuthorizationServiceImpl$InitializingOTPHolder.loadPort(OTPAuthorizationServiceImpl.java:366) ~[na:na]
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.itg.internal.services.OTPAuthorizationServiceImpl$InitializingOTPHolder.loadPort(OTPAuthorizationServiceImpl.java:344) ~[na:na]
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.itg.internal.services.holders.InitializingWSHolder.getPort(InitializingWSHolder.java:31) ~[na:na]
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.itg.internal.services.holders.SoapServiceEnpoint.getEndpoint(SoapServiceEnpoint.java:33) ~[na:na]
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.itg.internal.services.OTPAuthorizationServiceImpl.verifyCard_aroundBody0(OTPAuthorizationServiceImpl.java:98) ~[na:na]
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.itg.internal.services.OTPAuthorizationServiceImpl$AjcClosure1.run(OTPAuthorizationServiceImpl.java:1) ~[na:na]
    at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149) ~[aspectjrt-1.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.jcabi.aspects.aj.MethodLogger.wrap(MethodLogger.java:212) ~[jcabi-aspects-0.22.2.jar:na]
    at com.jcabi.aspects.aj.MethodLogger.ajc$inlineAccessMethod$com_jcabi_aspects_aj_MethodLogger$com_jcabi_aspects_aj_MethodLogger$wrap(MethodLogger.java:1) ~[jcabi-aspects-0.22.2.jar:na]
    at com.jcabi.aspects.aj.MethodLogger.wrapMethod(MethodLogger.java:169) ~[jcabi-aspects-0.22.2.jar:na]
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.itg.internal.services.OTPAuthorizationServiceImpl.__M_verifyCard(OTPAuthorizationServiceImpl.java:90) ~[na:na]
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.itg.internal.services.OTPAuthorizationServiceImpl.verifyCard(OTPAuthorizationServiceImpl.java) ~[na:na]
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.be.rest.resources.impl.UserPaymentToolsManager.getOTPEnabled(UserPaymentToolsManager.java:451) [rest-osgi-bundle-2.18.59.jar:na]
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.be.rest.resources.impl.UserPaymentToolsManager.getUserPaymentToolsInternal(UserPaymentToolsManager.java:211) [rest-osgi-bundle-2.18.59.jar:na]
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.be.rest.resources.impl.UserPaymentToolsManager.getUserPaymentTools(UserPaymentToolsManager.java:47) [rest-osgi-bundle-2.18.59.jar:na]
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.be.rest.resources.PaymentResource.getCartPaymentSummary(PaymentResource.java:431) [rest-osgi-bundle-2.18.59.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81) [jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144) [jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161) [jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205) [jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99) [jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389) [jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347) [jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102) [jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:309) [jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) [jersey-common-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) [jersey-common-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) [jersey-common-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) [jersey-common-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) [jersey-common-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317) [jersey-common-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:292) [jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1139) [jersey-server-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:460) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:334) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.21.jar:na]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:339) [org.apache.felix.http.bridge-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:300) [org.apache.felix.http.bridge-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:93) [org.apache.felix.http.bridge-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:50) [org.apache.felix.http.bridge-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31) [org.apache.felix.http.bridge-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:76) [org.apache.felix.http.bridge-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:49) [org.apache.felix.http.bridge-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67) [org.apache.felix.http.bridge-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750) [jakarta.servlet.jakarta.servlet-api.jar:4.0.2]
    at org.apache.felix.http.proxy.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60) [org.apache.felix.http.proxy-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750) [jakarta.servlet.jakarta.servlet-api.jar:4.0.2]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:295) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:353) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:250) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3865) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3832) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:344) [com.oracle.weblogic.security.subject.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197) [com.oracle.weblogic.security.subject.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.processSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2505) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2354) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2329) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2307) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1780) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1734) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272) [com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352) [com.bea.core.utils.full.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337) [com.bea.core.utils.full.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57) [com.oracle.weblogic.work.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:651) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:14.1.1.0]
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager.jar:14.1.1.0]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface xxx.xxx.xxx.itg.xxx.otp.FSBPxxxPayOTPPortType is not visible from class loader
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Proxy.java:581) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Proxy.java:557) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache$Factory.get(WeakCache.java:230) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache.get(WeakCache.java:127) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Proxy.java:419) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:719) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.ClientInstance.createProxyInstance(ClientInstance.java:160) ~[com.oracle.webservices.ws-star-impl.jar:na]
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider$ServiceDelegateImpl$3.apply(WLSProvider.java:1539) ~[com.oracle.webservices.wls.wls-soap-stack-impl.jar:na]
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider$ServiceDelegateImpl$3.apply(WLSProvider.java:1475) ~[com.oracle.webservices.wls.wls-soap-stack-impl.jar:na]
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.ClientIdentityRegistry.initClientIdentityFeatureAndCall(ClientIdentityRegistry.java:1450) ~[com.oracle.webservices.ws-star-impl.jar:na]
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider$ServiceDelegateImpl.getPort(WLSProvider.java:1471) ~[com.oracle.webservices.wls.wls-soap-stack-impl.jar:na]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:390) ~[com.sun.xml.ws.jaxws-rt.jar:2.3.2-1]
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider$ServiceDelegateImpl.getPort(WLSProvider.java:1435) ~[com.oracle.webservices.wls.wls-soap-stack-impl.jar:na]
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:372) ~[com.sun.xml.ws.jaxws-rt.jar:2.3.2-1]
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:139) ~[na:2.3.2]
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.itg.xxx.otp.FSBPxxxPayOTP.getSOAP11Port(FSBPxxxPayOTP.java:68) ~[na:na]
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.itg.internal.services.OTPAuthorizationServiceImpl$InitializingOTPHolder.loadPort(OTPAuthorizationServiceImpl.java:359) ~[na:na]
    ... 76 common frames omitted
```

the soap service interface is as follows:

```
package xxx.xxx.xxx.itg.xxx.otp;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.ws.Action;
import javax.xml.ws.Holder;
import javax.xml.ws.RequestWrapper;
import javax.xml.ws.ResponseWrapper;


/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01
 * Generated source version: 2.2
 * 
 */
@WebService(name = "FSBP_xxxyyyOTPPortType", targetNamespace = "http://otp.xxxyyy.ws.fsbp.xxx.it")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface FSBPxxxyyyOTPPortType {


    /**
     * 
     * @param prefissoInternazionale
     * @param result
     * @param alias
     * @param telefono
     * @param businessPartner
     * @param notes
     * @param cf
     * @param esitoCard
     * @param header
     */
    @WebMethod(action = "http://otp.xxxyyy.ws.fsbp.xxx.it/verificaStatoByAlias")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "verificaStatoByAlias", targetNamespace = "http://otp.xxxyyy.ws.fsbp.xxx.it/data", className = "xxx.xxx.xxx.itg.xxx.otp.VerificaStatoByAlias")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "verificaStatoResponse", targetNamespace = "http://otp.xxxyyy.ws.fsbp.xxx.it/data", className = "xxx.xxx.xxx.itg.xxx.otp.VerificaStatoResponse")
    @Action(input = "http://otp.xxxyyy.ws.fsbp.xxx.it/verificaStatoByAlias", output = "http://otp.xxxyyy.ws.fsbp.xxx.it/FSBP_xxxyyyOTPPortType/verificaStatoByAliasResponse")
    public void verificaStatoByAlias(
        @WebParam(name = "header", targetNamespace = "http://otp.xxxyyy.ws.fsbp.xxx.it/data")
        RequestHeader header,
        @WebParam(name = "businessPartner", targetNamespace = "http://otp.xxxyyy.ws.fsbp.xxx.it/data")
        BusinessPartner businessPartner,
        @WebParam(name = "cf", targetNamespace = "http://otp.xxxyyy.ws.fsbp.xxx.it/data")
        String cf,
        @WebParam(name = "alias", targetNamespace = "http://otp.xxxyyy.ws.fsbp.xxx.it/data")
        String alias,
        @WebParam(name = "notes", targetNamespace = "http://otp.xxxyyy.ws.fsbp.xxx.it/data")
        Note notes,
        @WebParam(name = "result", targetNamespace = "http://otp.xxxyyy.ws.fsbp.xxx.it/data", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
        Holder<Result> result,
        @WebParam(name = "esitoCard", targetNamespace = "http://otp.xxxyyy.ws.fsbp.xxx.it/data", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
        Holder<String> esitoCard,
        @WebParam(name = "prefissoInternazionale", targetNamespace = "http://otp.xxxyyy.ws.fsbp.xxx.it/data", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
        Holder<String> prefissoInternazionale,
        @WebParam(name = "telefono", targetNamespace = "http://otp.xxxyyy.ws.fsbp.xxx.it/data", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
        Holder<String> telefono);

   

}
```

Could someone help me figure out how to fix both of these problems?